rotate image as user scroll using intersection observer
I just saw a wonderful scroll animation in this site https://thehungryfamily.com/bon-bouquet-cafe/.
here as user scroll some icons keep rotating. i tried to mimic the same animation but failed to understand the logic.
what i did so far

use intersection observer to detect the icon/image container in the viewport
use intersection observer boundingClientRect.y to detect if the user scroll from top-bottom or bottom-top to change rotate behaviour
adding values in array for intersection observer threshold so that it keeps trigerring the observer callback

but still somehow i miss some logic. the challenge i am facing is determining the user scroll direction(is user scroll from top to bottom or from bottom to top)
here is my code
function getAngle(str)
{
  if(str)
  {
    let angle=str.split("(");
    let angleArr=angle[1].split("t");
    return parseFloat(angleArr[0]);
  }
}

const globeOptions = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
}
const globeCallback = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const currentY = entry.boundingClientRect.y
        const currentRatio = entry.intersectionRatio
        const isIntersecting = entry.isIntersecting;
        let prevAngle=
        entry.target.style.transform ? getAngle(entry.target.style.transform):0;
    
        if (currentY < previousY) {
          if (currentRatio > previousRatio && isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.style.transform=`rotate(${prevAngle+0.2}turn)`;
          } else {
            entry.target.style.transform=`rotate(${prevAngle+0.2}turn)`;
          }
        } else if (currentY > previousY && isIntersecting) {
          if (currentRatio < previousRatio) {
            entry.target.style.transform=`rotate(${-(prevAngle-0.2)}turn)`;
          } else {
            entry.target.style.transform=`rotate(${-(prevAngle-0.2)}turn)`;
          }
        }
    
        previousY = currentY
        previousRatio = currentRatio
    })
  }

const globeobserver = new IntersectionObserver(globeCallback, globeOptions)


const globeTarget = document.querySelector('.globe-box img')
globeobserver.observe(globeTarget)



I would only listen to the scroll event on the main listener and compute the rotation based on this information.
The computation might be a little more complex if you want to ensure the initial display of each element, but this approach ermains valid.


const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')

function handleScroll () {
  const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon')
  const rotate = container.scrollTop / 10
  icons.forEach((icon, index) => {
    icon.style.transform = `rotate(${index % 2 === 0 ? '' : '-'}${rotate}deg)`
  })
}
container.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}
.icon {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
.icon:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: url(https://thehungryfamily.com/storage/2024/07/BBV-illustration-elements-11.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon:nth-child(even) {

  background-image: url(https://thehungryfamily.com/storage/2024/07/BBV-illustration-elements-10.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class='container'>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
        <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='icon'></div>
  </div>
</div>



